# How to customize bindings/queues/Exchange behaviours correctly on Spring Cloud Dataflow custom app

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-dataflow, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm developing a custom app who inject the main function of time OOTB app, but I want to customize also the behaviour of the queues and Exchanges created at the moment of deploying a stream on SCDF, my current configuration is with the following properties at the moment of sending my API deployment POST:

```
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.auto-bind-dlq":"true",
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.deadLetterExchangeType":"topic",
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.deadLetterQueueName":"NameOfStream.dlq",
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.republish-to-dlq":"true"
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange":"DLX"
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.exchangeAutoDelete":"true",
"app.appExample.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.exchangeAutoDelete":"true"
}
```

This properties are used with all apps inside my stream.

But this configuration is sending me always this ERROR message for my first payload:

`2023-05-11 15:40:21.196 ERROR [log-sink,,] 1 --- [.0.109.185:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'test.http.test' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)`

Even though I explicitly put the name of the DLX, and with this error the first payload always get lost, it didn't even get routed to the dlq

I'm currently trying to use the following properties on my application-properties file, but after some tests I found that this properties don't do anything to the queues and exchanges:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=timeDemo-output
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.timeExtractor-out-0=output

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.autoBindDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange=DLX
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.republish-to-dlq=true

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.exchangeAutoDelete=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.deadLetterExchangeType=topic
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.dlqExpires=1000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.expires=1000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.consumer.exchangeAutoDelete=true
```

My current configuration of SCDF is just the server, the Skipper server and I'm using rabbitMQ server on docker.

So, how can I correct implement this behaviour? I get all of this properties from the current documentation of SCDF.

Comment: Where are you applying these properties? 
What would you like to achieve?

Comment: On my application.properties file

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve.  Double-check the names. Some of the properties are slightly different from what you used: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties